# Log sum likelihood in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch, neural-network, loss-function, log-likelihood

I have just started working with Pytorch and ML stuff. I have a loss function as below:

[Loss function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcvex.png)

I guess I can implement the first term with nn.GaussianNLLLoss, but does anyone know how can I implement the second term which is the log of sum gaussian likelihood?

Comment: inside the curly brackets: 1/m log(x).sum(-1) + log(1/m * x.sum(-1)).sum(-1).

but where the first curly brackets end ?

Comment: Can you clarify the indices?

Comment: The first brackets end just before the + sign.
And, regarding the indices, m goes for the data in dataset while l goes for choosing a sample "c" which is calculated based the data